# How can i create a pictureBox manually to be exactly between two panels on form1?

Tags: c#, winforms

My form1 size is 800,600
Then i have two panels in the form1 designer:

Panel1 is at location: 0,24 size: 200,437
Panel2 is at location: 584,24 size: 200,437

The result is two panels at each side of the form.
Now i did in my program when you put the mouse somewhere in the form1 area its showing a pictureBox i create in the form1 constructor:

```
pb = new AnimatedPictureBox.AnimatedPictureBoxs();
pb.Visible = false;
pb.Size = new Size(500, 350);
pb.Location = new Point((ClientSize.Width - pb.Width) / 2,
   (ClientSize.Height - pb.Height) / 2);
```

The problem is that the new pictureBox variable pb is not in the size that will fill all the area between the two panels.
I want the size of the pictureBox to fill almost all the space between the two panels Width and Height maybe to leave some space like 5 spaces each side so there will be a border.

How can i calculate what the pictureBox size should be ?

EDIT**

This is an image where the program is working regular. On each panel on the left and right i added 4 pictureBoxes.
When i move my mouse cursor inside one of the pictureBoxes area its showing its content in a larger pictureBox in the middle.

[image]

And this is how it looks like when i put the mouse cursor in one of the pictureBoxes area the pictureBox in the middle is not big enough its Width and Height dosent make the big pictureBox to be excatly between the two panels. The big pictureBox not high and not wide enough.

[image]

Comment: A graphical representation will help to understand your needs better

Comment: Updated my question withi mages show the big pictureBox the width is ok i guess but its height not good not hight enough on the top and also on the bottom it dosent get to the same place where the panels height is. I mean the panels borders top and bottom the big pictureBox should be also this height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make your layout stable even after resizing you should use `Dock` property for your panels and set `Anchor` for your picture box. Like that:

```
panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
pb.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

And in general to place it in the center you can use something like that:

```
var width = this.Width - panel1.Width - panel1.Margin.Horizontal
                - panel2.Width - panel2.Margin.Horizontal;

pb.Size = new Size(width, 300); // put your needed height here

pb.Top = this.Height/2 - pb.Height/ 2;
pb.Left = panel2.Left + panel2.Width + panel2.Margin.Right;
```

Comment: What is panel3 ? I dont have panel3 only panel1 and panel2